# How to access class parameter in anonymous object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

How can I access class members during the creation of an anonymous object?

```js
class foo {
   private working = 'hello';
   private notWorking = 'world';

   public method() {
      new DoSomethingClass(working, {
         ...,
         this.notWorking //this throws an error as this has a different scope now
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the approach to store `this` in another variable before the scope change? E.g. `const self = this;` right before you do `new DoSomethingClass` and then use `self` within the new scope. It may still not be possible to access a *private* property that way though.

Comment: Your class syntax is also wrong. The `:` are not valid there.

Comment: And it also may help to describe what you are trying to achieve. What do you want to inject in the `DoSomethingClass`? I am confused as to why you want to add the logic inside the `foo` class and not the `DoSomethingClass`.

Comment: I fixed the ":", this was just a typo. TheDoSomethingClass is from a lib and takes a parameter object. I want to pass the arguments to it that i have stored in a class.

Comment: I think you are missing the key of your config object. `{theKeyTheLibWants: this.notWorking}`

Comment: This is what I wanted to do: https://jsfiddle.net/jhbawd75/   I will try to pass the key next. Thanks :).

Comment: Thanks, the keys did the trick :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing a config object, make sure it uses the right key:

```
  new DoSomethingClass(working, {
     theRequiredKey: this.notWorking
  });
```

Check your library for the key names.

You can still use a shortcut for that you use the same variable name as the key is called, e.g.:

```
  const theRequiredKey = this.notWorking;
  new DoSomethingClass(working, {
     theRequiredKey, // will create an object with key "theRequiredKey" and its value
  });
```

This will work as wanted.

---

Also check if your library has typescript typings available, e.g. via

```
npm install @types/{library-name}
```

or create your own typings.

Answer (score 1):

At runtime there is no way to guarantee that `this` will have the right scope. A function's scope (proper term is "context") can be customized at call time with `bind`/`call`/`apply`, and if separated from it's object, it loses its original context:

```
var fn = instance.method;
fn(); // `this` will not be `instance` anymore
```

Arrow functions allow you to avoid this issue.

```
public method = () => { ... }
```

There are other ways like stashing `var _this = this`, but that's error prone.

Note: arrow class methods are different than regular class methods. Since they need to access instance variables, the typescript-generated function will not be on the prototype, but rather in the class constructor. Each instance will have a separate function instance, instead of all pointing to the same function instance. This might affect performance in hot code paths.